# file system error on non-existent device (ext4_mb_generate_buddy)

Tags: filesystems, lvm, kvm

Ubuntu 20.04 server running virtual server guests.

```
root@virtual3:/dev# dmesg | grep dm-11
[16067.090601] EXT4-fs (dm-11): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[16140.884093] EXT4-fs (dm-11): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[16208.242423] EXT4-fs (dm-11): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[16280.839903] EXT4-fs (dm-11): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[16400.942784] EXT4-fs (dm-11): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[16443.928439] EXT4-fs (dm-11): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[16443.929427] EXT4-fs (dm-11): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[16443.934501] EXT4-fs (dm-11): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[16443.949457] EXT4-fs error (device dm-11): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:1147: group 4, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 2731 vs 2732 free clusters
[41267.656921] EXT4-fs (dm-11): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[41310.767963] EXT4-fs (dm-11): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[41351.690443] EXT4-fs (dm-11): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[41393.912918] EXT4-fs (dm-11): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[41462.134997] EXT4-fs (dm-11): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[41474.884928] EXT4-fs (dm-11): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[41474.885747] EXT4-fs (dm-11): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[41474.890554] EXT4-fs (dm-11): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[41474.904432] EXT4-fs error (device dm-11): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:1147: group 4, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 2731 vs 2732 free clusters

root@virtual3:/dev# ls dm*
dm-0  dm-1  dm-10  dm-2  dm-3  dm-4  dm-5  dm-6  dm-7  dm-8  dm-9
```

As you can see there is no /dev/dm-11 so I'm not sure what to do next. The root drive is SSD (containing dm-0 to dm-8)and there is also a conventional hdd (which has dm-9 and dm-10 on it).

The system failed with a mysterious network problem which resolved by magic (ie: restarting systemd-networkd a few times) - I'm yet to figure out how and I've been unable to find anything in the logs. I don't know if the two problems are related.

As I write this everything seems to be working. smartctl doesn't report errors.